# Flutter Dart function is popping to the wrong widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code snippet is causing the widget to pop all the way back to my login page (which is not even in this file). It is supposed to just minimize the add task window that pops up and add a new row with the task and its info. The cancel button does it correctly, but _submitForm is sending me back to the login page. I tried passing in the BuildContext, but it did not work.

Here is the code, functions in question are :

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _submitForm(context),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          ),
          child: const Text(
            'Submit',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

And:

```
  void _submitForm(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      widget.onTaskAdded(Task(
        name: _taskName,
        assignees: _assignees,
        priority: _priority,
      ));
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
    print('bork');
  }
```

Full Code:

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors, library_private_types_in_public_api

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TaskListScreenState createState() => TaskListScreenState();
}

class TaskListScreenState extends State<TaskListScreen> {
  List<Task> tasks = [];

  void _addNewTask() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: AddTaskForm(
              onTaskAdded: (newTask) {
                setState(() {
                  tasks.add(newTask);
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TaskNinjaPlus'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[800],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Text(
                    'TaskNinjaPlus',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Text(
                      'Task',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      'Assignees',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Text(
                      'Priority',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _addNewTask,
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Add Task'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: tasks.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(tasks[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text(tasks[index].assignees),
                  trailing: Text(tasks[index].priority),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Task {
  final String name;
  final String assignees;
  final String priority;

  Task({required this.name, required this.assignees, required this.priority});
}

class AddTaskForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(Task) onTaskAdded;

  const AddTaskForm({required this.onTaskAdded});

  @override
  _AddTaskFormState createState() => _AddTaskFormState();
}

class _AddTaskFormState extends State<AddTaskForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String _taskName;
  late String _assignees;
  String _priority = 'Low';

  void _submitForm(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      widget.onTaskAdded(Task(
        name: _taskName,
        assignees: _assignees,
        priority: _priority,
      ));
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
    print('bork');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Add Task'),
      content: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter task details',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter the task details';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (value) => _taskName = value!,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter assignees',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter assignees';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (value) => _assignees = value!,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            DropdownButtonFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Select priority',
              ),
              value: _priority,
              items: ['Low', 'Moderate', 'High']
                  .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: label,
                        child: Text(label),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _priority = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 94, 27, 27),
          ),
          child: const Text(
            'Cancel',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _submitForm(context),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          ),
          child: const Text(
            'Submit',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to pass the context in, and it works, but it looks like it is passing in the wrong context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two navigation pop,

```dart
 void _submitForm(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      ...
     Navigator.pop(context); //one here
    print('bork');
  }
```

Another

```dart
child: AddTaskForm(
  onTaskAdded: (newTask) {
    setState(() {
      tasks.add(newTask);
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  },
),
),
```

Therefore it is getting called two times and going back to login screen, you can remove one of this.

Comment: Yep, it was popping back 2 times causing it to go to the login page. Thank you!!